# Quelle locution prépositive serait à privilégier dans « Quelle était la distance affichée à l’odomètre de mon véhicule à/lors de ma dernière visite?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Quelle locution prépositive serait à privilégier: à, lors de ou à l’occasion de?

Merci.

Quelle était la distance affichée à l’odomètre de mon véhicule à/lors de/ à l’occasion de ma dernière visite d’entretien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Lors de* me semble le plus indiqué mais en France, la phrase la plus idiomatique serait :

> Il y avait combien de km au compteur de ma voiture lors de ma dernière révision ?

Comment: Il ne faudrait pas confondre « idiomatique » et « très commun » ; « Quelle était la distance affichée à l’odomètre de mon véhicule à  ma dernière visite? » est _parfaitement_ idiomatique.

Comment: @LPH Ton assurance l'est plus encore... Comment peux-tu considérer une phrase qui utilise un mot inconnu de mon garagiste et une préposition douteuse comme *parfaitement idiomatique* ?

Comment: On trouve des quantités de cette expression même (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%A0%20ma%20derni%C3%A8re%20visite%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) et je croit qu'un mot du type de «  odomètre », comme il touche au domaine technique de l'automobile, a encore plus de chance d'être connu d'un mécanicien intéressé par sa profession. De tout façon, on ne doit absolument pas mélanger « rare »  et « non idiomatique », ce sont des concepts **totalement** différents.

Comment: @LPH Idiomatique veut dire ici « qui a les caractéristiques d'une phrase écrite par quelqu'un dont le français est la langue maternelle », ou « authentique » si tu préfères, le *Eigentlichkeit* d'Heidegger... Par exemple, puisque tu connais mieux l'anglais que le français, je ne crois pas qu'un anglophone trouverait idiomatique la phrase suivante: *How many kilometers was there at the counter of my car during my last maintenance visit*

Comment: @LPH  [Merriam-Webster: Idiomatic. Did You Know?](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiomatic)
*The speech and writing of a native-born English-speaker may seem crude, uneducated, and illiterate, but will almost always be idiomatic—that is, a native speaker always sounds like a native speaker. For a language learner, speaking and writing idiomatically in another language is the greatest challenge. Even highly educated foreign learners—professors, scientists, doctors, etc.—rarely succeed in mastering the kind of idiomatic English spoken by an American 7th-grader.*

Comment: Il y a beaucoup de vrai dans ce que vous dites (sauf que je comprends mieux l'anglais, c'est l'inverse parce que je ne l'ai pas étudié énormément),mais il n'en reste pas moins que l'idiomaticité est une question de syntaxe essentiellement ; Wikipédia (idiomatisme) : Les constructions non idiomatiques, bien qu’elles soient tout à fait compréhensibles, ont une consonance de **solécisme** pour les gens parlant couramment la langue. (solécisme) : Un solécisme est une erreur de langage qui enfreint les règles de la syntaxe (la forme existe), non celles de la morphologie ( barbarisme).

Comment: La propriété (eigentlichkeit) est bien une idée qui concerne l'idiomaticité mais on n'en parle jamais en évoquant la philosophie d'Heidegger où il semble que le mot prenne une signification particulière ; le sens de base du français courant est tout ce dont on a besoin, mais ce mot ne sert qu'à une description très générale et n'est pas suffisant ; on doit être plus spécifique.

Comment: Pourquoi limiter l'adjectif *idiomatique* à la syntaxe et considérer qu'il ne peut s'appliquer qu'à *expression*? On peut très bien parler de *vocabulaire idiomatique* ou de phrase plus ou moins idiomatique. Une expression est idiomatique ou elle ne l'est pas alors qu'un mot ou une phrase peuvent l'être plus ou moins. *Odomètre* par exemple est un mot qui existe dans le lexique français mais que personne n'utilise. Si quelqu'un l'emploie, on peut supposer qu'il a en tête l'anglais *odometer*. Cette phrase sera donc moins idiomatique que si elle contenait *compteur* ou *compteur kilométrique*.

Comment: @LPH *Visite d'entretien* c'est pareil. Personne ne dit *Bonjour, j'ai rendez-vous pour la visite d'entretien de mon véhicule*. Le garagiste comprendra mais se dira que le client est bizarre. Ce qu'il a l'habitude d'entendre, c'est par exemple *Bonjour, j'ai rendez-vous pour la révision des vingt mille*. Ça, c'est idiomatique !

Comment: Le mot courant qui correspond à compteur kilométrique en anglais est « speedometer », pas « odometer » (même chose qu'en français, « odometer » est rare, technique).   « Cette phrase sera moins idiomatique » : oui, si on fait de la fréquence d'emploi  un critère d'idiomaticité, ce que personne n'a fait jusqu'à présent à ma connaissance. Ce que vous faites c'est ajouter un autre critère aux critères déterminant l'idiomaticité et il ne s'agit plus alors de la même chose. Il est certain que vous n'allez pas parler à une femme qui n'a jamais possédé de voiture d'une visite des   (1/2)

Comment: vingt mille et qu'elle comprendra bien « visite d'entretient », ce qui suffit ; il n'y a pas de forme plus ou moins idiomatique que l'autre : il n'est même pas question de registre et on n'est concerné que par une notion comme le contexte social d'emploi ; l'idiomaticité ne prend pas non plus cela en compte.  La forme peut ne pas être usuelle mais elle reste syntaxiquement correcte et compréhensible. Si un terme spécifique est nécessaire à la compréhension, les locuteurs sont toujours à  temps de se corriger et de se comprendre et ils sont libres de choisir leurs termes. (2/2)

Comment: Non, un *odometer* n'est pas un *speedometer*, un compteur kilométrique n'est pas un compteur de vitesse. Je ne retiendrai que ta dernière phrase « les locuteurs sont libres de choisir leurs termes ». Tiens-t'en là et laisse-moi donc choisir *idiomatique* pour mesurer le degré de conformité d'un mot ou d'une phrase avec le français qu'utilisent ceux dont c'est la langue maternelle.